# Heroku CI and/or Travis CI

Tags: django, heroku, travis-ci

We are using Heroku to host our Django application. We also use Heroku CI with pipelines and tests running after each push to our staging. Is there any advantage/difference in using Travis CI instead? I see it in so many projects but haven't used it before.